# ArrayList occurance of object type

Tags: java

I have a class of orders and I want to see how many times a unique customerNumber will get mapped to a status reading "On Hold"

```
public class Orders {
private String status = null;
private int customerNumber = 0;

public Orders(String status, int customerNumber) {
    super();
    this.status = status;
    this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
}
}




public int NumberOfOrdersOnHold(List<Orders> orders) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Orders o : orders) {
        if(o.getStatus().contentEquals("On Hold"));
    }

}
```

I was thinking a counter method would work but it wouldnt. how will i achieve this method.I need numbers of orders in hold for each customerNumber not the total number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.List;

enum OrderStatus {
    ONHOLD("On Hold"), APPROVED("Approved"), DELIVERED("Delivered");

    private final String statusCode;

    private OrderStatus(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}

class Order {
    private OrderStatus status = null;
    private int customerNumber = 0;

    public Order(OrderStatus status, int customerNumber) {
        this.status = status;
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    public OrderStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(OrderStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getCustomerNumber() {
        return customerNumber;
    }

    public void setCustomerNumber(int customerNumber) {
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [status=" + status + ", customerNumber=" + customerNumber + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Order> orders = List.of(new Order(OrderStatus.ONHOLD, 1234), new Order(OrderStatus.APPROVED, 1234),
                new Order(OrderStatus.ONHOLD, 2345), new Order(OrderStatus.APPROVED, 1234),
                new Order(OrderStatus.ONHOLD, 1234), new Order(OrderStatus.ONHOLD, 2345));
        System.out.println("Customer#1234 has " + numberOfOrdersOnHold(orders, 1234) + " order(s) on hold");
    }

    static int numberOfOrdersOnHold(List<Order> orders, int customerNumber) {
        int count = 0;
        for (Order order : orders) {
            if (order.getCustomerNumber() == customerNumber && order.getStatus() == OrderStatus.ONHOLD) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Customer#1234 has 2 order(s) on hold
```

**Notes:**

1. Use `enum` for status values as it makes easy for you to write and maintain the code. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to learn more about Java `enum`.
2. Follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. `NumberOfOrdersOnHold` should be named as `numberOfOrdersOnHold`.
3. The function, `numberOfOrdersOnHold` also requires the customer number whose order status has to be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)! Try something like this:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> numberOfOrdersOnHold(List<Orders> orders) {
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Orders o : orders) {
        int currentNumber = o.getCustomerNumber();

        // if map doesn't contain the key to the corresponding customer, were gonna add it
        if (!map.containsKey(currentNumber)) {
            map.put(currentNumber, 0);
        }

        // if the status is "On hold", increment the counter to the current customer
        if ("On hold".equals(o.getStatus())) {
            map.put(currentNumber, map.get(currentNumber) + 1);
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```